# Multiple SLF4J bindings, how to find offending dependency

Tags: slf4j

I'm getting following error:

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/mmucha/.m2/repository/org/apache/activemq/activemq-all/5.15.8/activemq-all-5.15.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/mmucha/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

I know, from it, that log4jLoggerFactory was generously brought by activemq. `mvn dependency:tree` shows me nothing, checking pom.xml files in activemq jar files showed me some dependencies, but so far I setup following exclusions, and I still cannot kill it.

Question: what is the proper way of finding conflict? Which exclusion am I missing?

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
      <version>5.15.8</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE/BONUS QUESTION:**

I did nothing to the configuration, but run several times mysterious&deprecated command:
`mvn -U idea:idea`

I have no idea what that does, but everytime idea does some super-crazyness, it helps it a little. So after this cure, the actual binding changed to:

```
Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

meaning I finally get readable logs, however, the annoying warning stays, thus so does the original question. And any explanations of goal idea:idea fixing otherwise unfixable idea would be also welcomed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Which IDE you are using?

IntelliJ:- Open your pom.xml

Press
ALT+CNTRL+SHIFT+U  or RightClick Diagram -> Show Dependencies

Now it will popup a diagram window where you can search your dependencies

activemq-all-5.15.8.jar and logback-classic-1.2.3.jar

It will show you a pictorial view of all dependencies. You can see the parent JAR who is including these JARs and you can exclude whichever JAR you really  do not want to use.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Actually I use IDEA. I don't understand these dependencies diagrams that much. This is what I see: https://pasteboard.co/I4wAbxs.png  Ie. you cannot even see any dependency on anything log4j or slf4j related stuff leading from activemq. Yet we know from slf4j itself, that offending library is activemq, as I want the other one, the logback classic.

Comment: Well here either you have to remove whole ActiveMQ dependency or exclude slf4j from logback JAR. What you are trying to do it trying to exclude slf4j JAR from ActiveMQ. However there is no sl4j JAR under ActiveMQ it is just the same class StaticLoggerBinder available in ActiveMQ with the package structure same as it used to be slf4j.

Comment: uhm. Sorry, I don't get it. Just minutes ago, I was getting some log4j messages and logback.xml was entirelly ignored. After `mvn -U idea:idea` the situation is OK, but I don't understand your suggestion. And have no idea where did log4j came from nor where did it go :) Can you elaborate a little more about your suggestion?

Comment: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/mmucha/.m2/repository/org/apache/activemq/activemq-all/5.15.8/activemq-all-5.15.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]    If you look at this the class StaticLoggerBinder is inside activemq-all-5.15.8.jar . What we were trying to exclude is  slf4j-log4j12.jar inside activemq

Comment: Sorry, this is over my head. Plus ActiveMQ is logging like crazy in debug level in log4j style and I'm unable to control it. `Simple` in SLF4J is truly sarcastical. Btw. I really wonder, why do I have to remove slf4j-nop from m2 to get rid of stupid warnings if I do not even declare it in pom. I guess I will eradicate every mention of slf4j in this small tool, because this `simple` logging is just creating insane problems.
Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Seems that I'm not the first one, who stepped on this landmine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164057/maven-dependency-causing-slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings

Comment: ~ Do you actually know, what actions need to be taken to resolve this? Either I'm stupid or I don't know. Is there anything to be excluded in this case? What action could I do to find what should be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Here the working and tested example for resolve it:

```
<dependencies>
<!-- Spring JMS -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ActiveMQ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-test.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```